# What happens to subscribers when the Kafka service is down? Do the need to subscribes to a specific topic when it restart?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue

Currently I have to sent events externally to the client which needs to subscribe to the these events. I have an endpoint that the client calls (subscribe) that follow the Server-Sent Events specifications. This open a HTTP connection, that is kept alive by the server that send "heartbeat" events.

The problem is that when this service need to be redeployed, or it goes down is the responsibility of the client to re-subscribe making a call to this endpoint, to receive again the events in real-time.

I was wondering, if I switch to technology like rabbitMQ or Kafka can I solve this problem? In other word, I would like to remove the responsibility of the client to re-subscribe if something goes wrong on the server side.

If you can attached article/resources to your answer would be great.

Comment: Kafka consumer threads also have heartbeats and periodically TCP connections are made. They will need restarted if there's a very long disconnect

Answer (score 0):

With RabbitMQ , the reconnection feature is dependant on the client library. For e.g., Java and .NET clients do provide this ( check [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connections.html#automatic-recovery))
With Kafka I see there are [configurations](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_reconnect.backoff.ms) to support this. Also it's worth reading the excellent recommendations from Kakfa for surviving broker outages [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-survive-a-kafka-outage/).

Comment: Yes. but I was talking about services in different places, not services in the same microservice infrastructure. A web socket is needed. I'm not so familiar with rabbitmq and kafka, if they can be used even in this case.